# Vega-Lite : Cross lines when hovering a cell - Heatmap

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to make an interactive Heatmap with Vega-Lite. I want to show cross lines when hovering a cell to put forward Y-axis and X-axis labels. Indeed, I know it's possible to display a tooltip but it's not what I'm searching for. Is it possible (because I did not find a way to do it) ?

[Here's what I'm trying to do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq0dD.png)

Below is the code and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAMyUAVhDYA7EABoQTJFADWZAE5sGsgCZoQAYgBmTM2cUgA7jT31DUOZiQ1ZcTVfg0yWR89d3TyU9JBc0UGIkQQY4CDQAbVAABW1JOChMAGk4AE9DACUAQQBlKwAZNzU4PVS2dMyc-PRy4rKlAFk4TE0aKDQAJgAGAF8FFLSM7LzDAGEAeXaQStlq2snGmZa2qy6evrQARlHxkDqG6eaQHaUVtfOpprnF3e7e-tQAdjGJ+set5Y3ZZVGoPTZXEoASQAcq99h9DgMfmcNpdnks7qDUU90FDYZ03gdUAAWZFgtHbUoVEHrP7gwwAFSK+JAe3eR2+AF0xiA4LInHo3GQIiBmqATDQ4IIDOhyU8lJhcjg4IZZGwEG5olYkAAPGjxVCgQRIJhSyoazBHIajHk6kUSqUy4GrLF0tEKpUq9BqjWyLVKXX6kXG02CIqyMiCL38AYAViUIbNNAtaE+sZGGYTSFyHkSoGQmjUIsVysMmimVkwbDYgkwNBwaB6sR5fIFQpFTkEbE8hpASDIWj4mC9IAgDAQVgd0sMbIOHtL6AAjgwkLI6y466QrNBol7QJpV2QvQkQMJfJgmDEVQmfFhB3yrKYTJ9nyYQNyFXQo4ZoePTZoAAI2BMADZ36DNkQLItexLEdhx1S0FWrWt60bTRmyUVs2EFCNizgBD7Ulad0DAytPUMZdV3XMIaC3HlO27EUoivQxL1UIsIO5IA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "background": "#fbfbfb",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ProjectKey": "RAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "LRAS", "Metric": 20},
      {"ProjectKey": "COS", "LinkedProjectKey": "LRAS", "Metric": 10},
      {"ProjectKey": "RAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "COS", "Metric": 7},
      {"ProjectKey": "LRAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "SIN", "Metric": 12},
      {"ProjectKey": "COS", "LinkedProjectKey": "SIN", "Metric": 4},
      {"ProjectKey": "LRAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "TAN", "Metric": 17}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "ProjectKey",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelLimit": 100}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "LinkedProjectKey",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": -25, "labelLimit": 75}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "Metric",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"range": ["lightblue", "lightgreen", "#ff7f7f"]},
          "title": "Number of Metric"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Metric", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you help me ? Thanks by advance ! ^^

Comment: Can you add some sample so that we can try on your problem

Comment: @wahabmemon I think I can't edit the post..
[Here's a link with a sample](shorturl.at/abN15)

Comment: On hover of a cell, you just need the red lines displayed in image right ?

Comment: Yes if it's possible I want to display red lines to show label axis. As an example, I hover the  COS/SIN cell, it displays red lines and put forward COS label & SIN label. I don't know if it's clear 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 more layers having `rule` marks. Each having a constant x and y seperate to cover the entire line.
Then on `select` params of mouseover you can set color conditions and make other rule transparent and only display the hovered line.
Refer the code and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQTJFADWZAE5sGsgCZoQAYgBmTM2cUgA7jT31DUOZiQ1ZcTVfg0yWR89d3TyU9JBc0UGIkQQY4CDQAbVAABW1JOChMAGk4AE9DACUAQQBlKwAZNzU4PVS2dMyc-PRy4rKlAFk4TE0aKDQAJgAGAF8FFLSM7LzDAGEAeXaQStlq2snGmZa2qy6evrQARlHxkDqG6eaQHaUVtfOpprnF3e7e-tQAdjGJ+set5Y3ZZVGoPTZXEoASQAcq99h9DgMfmcNpdnks7qDUU90FDYZ03gdUAAWZFgtHbUoVEHrP7gwwAFSK+JAe3eR2+AF0xiA4LInHo3GQIiBmqATDQ4IIDOhyU8lJhcjg4IZZGwEG5olYkAAPGjxVCgQRIJhSyoazBHIajHk6kUSqUy4GrLF0tEKpUq9BqjWyLVKXX6kXG02CIqyMiCL38AZiJQhs00C1oT5iEbphWaJCyCAmNiaBCJUBQaJQBjGzBekCHbUGkCactwFYqkac+NIXIeIsgHBILMIA1JEB+hBVmA+GDCXyWpQQKVTEWK5WGHBsNwzkByQwIHRztikYK8-lsQURwcgO1KfLc5EjqtzqOZKwPhfoVfrkCtpTITRqReewxNAXBU2DYQRMBoHA0B6WIeT5AUhRFJxBHzEUkDILQ+ErQwIAYQslAdaVDDZA4PWXdAAEcGGzCCXAg0hnxLKMRSzCMvQSEApywJgYhVeMJ0wTC+SsUwTE+MSTBAbkFToZj0GhPDTU0AACNgTGUkj+nTZEfz-Q0QCXKtKx1DdMFA8DIOghs4Dg49T2FfSxRAQinTlGYyKrH1NUEbU9QNWRy0EW17UlIiWhpNz8g81V1W83yg1QALBCChU4BMkLHWIwl+miyjqNkWiwhoBieWQ1D9KiXjDB41Q-2005dP-cj60bKwzLAiCoNQGC4H49wrNgpR4JPRD9LtfSXMMTFaQueUDIA71Yr9HyAz8tAkpS0UMrClqo2bNqFpAKiaLoIqGNWhKNtKsDyuLORBQgrdUCHXt+0McdfC4jdEBwRU0BMaI5yUSrYkAmpPzbEAQaM1iIFevlLXq0BGv0wzANakCOss7rrKUMrPHQICDD6r0etshCIxFJzJtlbF3Pm5qvOW+L-MC4KJtCp0Gz2tw+IZqtjoK076L5wNWeS66UIJu79Dodh5Ge0BXqQQt0A+ycBKsH6-tQAHBCBqHolBwnwa-Q2qvQHpszhvsEc-dNuSAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "background": "#fbfbfb",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ProjectKey": "RAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "LRAS", "Metric": 20},
      {"ProjectKey": "COS", "LinkedProjectKey": "LRAS", "Metric": 10},
      {"ProjectKey": "RAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "COS", "Metric": 7},
      {"ProjectKey": "LRAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "SIN", "Metric": 12},
      {"ProjectKey": "COS", "LinkedProjectKey": "SIN", "Metric": 4},
      {"ProjectKey": "LRAS", "LinkedProjectKey": "TAN", "Metric": 17}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "ProjectKey",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelLimit": 100}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "LinkedProjectKey",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": -25, "labelLimit": 75}
    }
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "1", "as": "ruleLine"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "highlight",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "on": "mouseover",
            "encodings": ["x", "y"]
          }
        },
        {"name": "select", "select": "point"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "Metric",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"range": ["lightblue", "lightgreen", "#ff7f7f"]},
          "title": "Number of Metric"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "ProjectKey", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
        "x": {"field": "LinkedProjectKey", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
        "text": {"field": "Metric", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": true, "line": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "LinkedProjectKey", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
        "y": {"field": "ruleLine", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
        "color": {
          "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "red"}],
          "value": "transparent"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": true, "color": "red", "line": true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "ProjectKey", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
        "x": {"field": "ruleLine", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
        "color": {
          "condition": [{"param": "highlight", "empty": false, "value": "red"}],
          "value": "transparent"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it's exactly what I needed !